# can getElementById be called on something else than document?

Tags: javascript, document, getelementbyid

I'm wondering and did not find anything on it.

I'm running some encapsulated javascript, so I can't/don't want to access `document`.

So instead of:

```
document.getElementById("foo");
```

I want to call `getElementById` on my top-encapsulated document like:

```
someNode.getElementById("foo");
```

which does not seem to work.

**Question:**
Is this at all possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you root from a specific node? IDs are supposed to be unique and only exist once in the page.

Comment: `getElementById()` is strictly only defined on `document`.

Comment: Because I'm inside a "supposedly" sandboxed environment, where document is not available. I can only go up to a certain "parent level"

Comment: @frequent what things are available in your sandbox? maybe we can negotiate with it or tunnel through it.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: Sandbox is called "gadget" and gadget.dom is a div ala `<div id="gadget_id">sandboxed contents</div>`. So my top element would be `$('div#gadget_id')`

Comment: I do not completely understand your scenario however the first thing that came to mind was using firebug to analyze the structure of whatever you have to work with and going from there. if this is possible

Comment: @frequent you using jQuery by any chance?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: yes, that would be easy. We do have jQuery inside the sandbox, but I wanted to see if I can do it with javascript only, so I was curious if I can call `getElementbyId` on something other than document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No :) if you want to do that, use querySelector

```
var nodes = div.querySelectorAll('[move_id]');
```

But you have to know that `getElementById` is more optimized !